# How to find the function called on button click

Tags: winapi, memory, assembly, machine-code, memory-editing

Using programs like [Cheat Engine](http://cheatengine.org/) and [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html) I'm editing the memory of a program as it's running.

I need to find the address of a function that is executed when the user clicks a certain button.

*Are there any tutorials available that show how to do this?*

*And is there any software available that will trace the currently executing code?*

I'm trying to build upon and extend a software application, my client no longer has the source code.

Answer (score 0):

First you search the memory for the string displayed, after that you put a onread memory breakpoint, you'll determine where it is used and after after that you start walking the call stack. Step by step breakpoint until you reach the place where the condition, you want to pass, is located. There are tons of tutorials, books, but it is also hard work...

More *info* [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=remove+nag+screen+tutorials&oq=remove+nag+screen+tutorials&sugexp=chrome,mod=12&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

More *books* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015986/interesting-books-on-reverse-engineering)